# Chrome extension opening page in a tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm having troubles with my chrome extension.
My background page send a file in an executeScript to the active tab to add a new div in it. It works fine.
After that I want to fill the div with the content of "popin.html", which is in my extension. To do so, I'm sending another executeScript to that tab, doing $("#popin").load("popin.html"), but this page isn't known by the tab since it's stored in my extension. 
Is there a way to pass that file to the tab ? Or to load another path that knows my extension, like $("#popin").load("myExtension/popin.html") perhaps ?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: "Resources would then be available in a webpage via the URL `chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH]`"

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL

Comment: Thanks a lot, the getUrl worked perfectly.